# System.Text.Json does not camelize properties of the dynamic property

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, system.text.json, camelcasing

I'm using ASP.NET Core and `System.Text.Json`.

Here's my sample action method:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public object Person()
    {
        dynamic relatedItems = new ExpandoObject();
        relatedItems.LastName = "Last";
        var result = new 
        {
            FirstName = "First",
            RelatedItems = relatedItems
        };
        return result;
    }
```

And here's what I get in response:

```
{
    firstName: "First",
    relatedItems: {
        LastName: "Last"
    }
}
```

As you can see, `LastName` which is a property of the dynamic property, is not camelized.

How can I make everything return in camel case?

**Update**. That answer is not my answer. As you can see I already have `firstName` property being correctly camelized.

Comment: Can confirm this one is not a duplicate of that post

Comment: I am sorry your question got closed, I believe it's a bug and sent a report [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/62101). In the meantime, I suggest switching to Dictionary or anonymous type if possible instead of `ExpandoObject`.

Comment: Found the fix for you btw, check [this comment](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/62101#issuecomment-980790290). `ExpandoObject` is considered Dictionary, so you need to set `DictionaryKeyPolicy` instead of `PropertyNamingPolicy`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ExpandoObject` will be treated as dictionary, so you need to set `DictionaryKeyPolicy` in addition to `PropertyNamingPolicy`:

```cs
dynamic relatedItems = new ExpandoObject();
relatedItems.LastName = "Last";
var result = new 
{
    FirstName = "First",
    RelatedItems = relatedItems
};
var s = JsonSerializer.Serialize(result, new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
    DictionaryKeyPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase
});
Console.WriteLine(s); // prints {"firstName":"First","relatedItems":{"lastName":"Last"}}
```